# Regex: spliting first, last name into comma-separated list eg "john smith Jr." to "john", "smith", "Jr."

Tags: c#, regex

I am using C# (asp .net) and I have a text box that accepts name entries that performs query on a DB.

I want to use the `IN` clause to obtain all possible values but in my c# page I get 1 string

e.g 'john smith' so I use  regex to break it into  'john','smith'

```
string text1 = "'"+Regex.Replace(text,@"[^A-Za-z0-9\-\.\']+","','")+"'";
```

however for names like 'John smith Jr.' or 'Bruce O'Brien',  it fails (due to the special characters)

What am I missing in my regex?

Thanks

Comment: Why not use [`string.Split();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)?

Comment: Recommended reading when dealing with names: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting to resolve this, I found a regex that works. It may be useful to someone else

```
private Regex regex = new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9\x27\x2D\x2E,\\s]");
```

where

- A-Za-z mean alpha
- 0-9 numeric
- \x27 APOSTROPHE (p.s. if this is going to be in a query run in DB add a second ' to escape)
- \x2D HYPHEN or MINUS
- \x2E FULL STOP or PERIOD

Here is the list of complete options: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex

Then to make the list, first I check `regex.IsMatch(searchterm)`, to make:

```
text = " ' " + Regex.Replace(text," ","','") + " ' ";
```

This results in *John Smith Jr.* giving *'John','Smith','Jr.'*; or *Kevin O'Neil* giving *'Kevin', 'O'Neil'*.

Thank you guys for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

Regex is not the easiest way to do this. Instead, I'd recommend the [String.Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), which works by defining what the whitespace characters between the words are:

```
string fullname = "Bruce O'Brien";
string[] names;
Char[] separators = new Char [] {' '}; // only the space character, in this case

names = fullname.Split(separators);
```

Once you've got an array of names, it's easy to turn that into a csv string if that's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by others, `String.Split()` probably makes more sense here.

However, I think you'll have an uphill battle. I did this to break up first and last names in an existing database and I found there were a lot of variations on how people can enter their names. Consider middle names, prefixes, suffixes, etc.

I've published the code I eventually used in the article [Splitting a Name into First and Last Names](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/splitting-a-name-into-first-and-last-names).

You might want to consider using a similar approach.